# Call getDirectRoutingCalls via web.content instead fo odata.Feed in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get some Teams call logs in Power BI and managed to do it via Graph API by doing OData.Feed call

```
 OData.Feed("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/callRecords/getDirectRoutingCalls(fromDateTime="&DateTime.ToText(Date.AddDays(DateTime.LocalNow(),-1),"yyyy-MM-dd")&",toDateTime="&DateTime.ToText(DateTime.LocalNow(),"yyyy-MM-dd")&")", [ Authorization = "Bearer " & access_token ], [ ExcludedFromCacheKey = {"Authorization"}, ODataVersion = 4, Implementation = "2.0" ])
```

But when I load it to PowerBI service it complains about dynamic data. Some people on forumns suggest using Web.Contents instead or moving url parameters to Query argument but not showing how to do it
Anybody have any idea on how it can be done?
Thanks